# How to renew a key expiration date in python gnupg?

Tags: python, gnupg, pgp

How do I renew a key's expiration date using the library `gnupg` in python? I've listed the key details and they're expired as of now. The only method I've seen so for in renewing these keys is via `pgp` itself, which I do not have access to at the moment.

Here is my [reference](https://python-gnupg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gnupg.html)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177291/how-to-renew-an-expired-keypair-with-gpg

Comment: Hi @RichardRublev, as I've mentioned in my question, I did see answer pointing to the usage of `pgp` itself, but I would like to renew the keys using the `gnupg` python library.